# Can't get a CSS Background behind a badge with z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have two graphical elements: One Badge for a Region (EUW) and a Sold Out Stamp. I want that the stamp is in front of the region badge. I always thought that this is something where I can use z-index but this just doesn't work for me.

Here is an image of my problem: [image]

**My CSS:**

```
.region-badge {
    position: absolute;
    top: 26px;
    right: 26px;
    background: url(../images/region_badge.png) no-repeat;
    height: 47px;
    width: 47px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 47px;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 1;
}
.sold-out {
    position:relative;
}
.sold-out::before{
    content: url(../images/sold_out_stamp2.png);
    transform: scale(.5);
    position:absolute;
    z-index: 40;
    top:-50px;
    left:70px;
}
```

**My HTML:**

```
<div class="rotate sold-out">
    <a href="images/packages/background01.jpg" rel="imagebox" title="SockMonkee">
        <img src="images/packages/background01.jpg" alt=""/></a>
</div>
<div class="region-badge">euw</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle as soon as possible.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.,

```
<div class="rotate sold-out">
    <a href="images/packages/background01.jpg" rel="imagebox" title="SockMonkee">
        <img src="images/packages/background01.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
   <div class="region-badge">euw</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @kentor: please accept this answer so the question summary indicates that it is answered

Comment: @sleek Geek sure,he use a `position:absolute` on `.region-badge` then it position in to the outer of `position:relative` so i changed the structure of parent `relative` and child `absolute`